# VT100 ANSI escape sequences: getting screen size, conditional ANSI

Tags: linux, escaping, ansi-escape, vt100

1. When I resizing  on terminal, it keeps full screen.
   I guess, there's someway that  can find out what screen size the terminal is. How can I do that in VT100?
2. With , when I list  folder, it shows folder in blue color. (or let's say different color) But, if you save output into a text file ( ls > out.txt ), you don't see any ANSI code but plain text. However, if you try ( vi > out.txt ), you will see ANSI code. How does  know that?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Programs (such as `vi`) which automatically adjust to screen resizing are responding to the `SIGWINCH` signal, and using a system call to obtain the system's information about the screen-size.  See for example *[Get width/height of a terminal window in c++?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-width-height-of-a-terminal-window-in-c-810739/)*.  By the way, though widely implemented, it does not appear to be documented in POSIX [`signal.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43).

Without taking `SIGWINCH` into account, a program could *ask* the terminal about its screensize.  The [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program does this, by sending the terminal control sequences to

- move the cursor to the lower-right corner (actually, to row/column 999/999, which is good enough), and
- asking the terminal where the cursor really is.

The behavior of `ls` and `vi` (and other programs) regarding ANSI control sequences which would be embedded in their output depends upon the design of the program.  They likely detect the redirection of their output to a file using the [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) function, and do something different depending on whether the output is to a terminal, or to a file.

Comment: Terminal programs (and libraries like ncurses) don't use the cursor movement technique but rather use `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl.

Comment: Your comment is not relevant to the answer (which already points to a sample program using termios).

Comment: @sim642 Thanks for providing information on common practices; very relevant to the answer!